# Error Handling for XML parser

Tags: ruby, parsing, error-handling, xml

I have the following Ruby code, which parses an XML document sax style (it's a very simplified version):

```
require 'nokogiri'

class ParsingError < RuntimeError; end

class Parser
  def initialize mapper, collector, error_collector
    @error_collector = error_collector
    @sax_handler = Handler.new(collector, @error_collector, mapper)
  end

  def process io_stream
    parser = Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(@sax_handler)
    parser.parse_io(io_stream, 'UTF-8')
  rescue ParsingError => e
    @error_collector << "ParsingError: #{e.message}"
  end
end

class Handler < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  def initialize collector, error_collector, mapper
    @mapper = mapper
    @collector = collector
    @error_collector = error_collector
  end

  def start_element name, attrs=[]
    return if name=='nodes'
    @current_element = @mapper.new(name)
  end

  def end_element name, attrs=[]
    return if @current_element.nil?
    data = @current_element.get_errors
    if data[:errors].empty?
      @collector << @current_element.result
    else
      @error_collector << data
    end
    @current_element = nil
  end

  def characters string
    @current_element.record(string) if @current_element
  end

  def error message
    raise ParsingError, message
  end
end

class Mapper
  def initialize name
    @data = ""
    @name = name
  end

  def record str
    @data << str
  end

  def result
    {name: @name, data: @data} # here are more properties
  end

  def get_errors
    arr = []
    if @data.index("Error 123")
      arr << "Error Code 123"
    elsif @data.index("Error 456")
      arr << "Error Code 456"
    elsif @data.index("Error 789")
      arr << "Error Code 789"
      # and a lot more validations
    end
    {name: @name, errors: arr}
  end
end

# Example usage
xml = %{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <nodes>
    <node1>some more data</node1>
    <node2>data Error 123</node2>
    <malformed xml
  </nodes>
}
collector = []
error_collector = []
mapper = Mapper
parser = Parser.new(Mapper, collector, error_collector)
parser.process(StringIO.new(xml))
puts "Data:"
puts collector
puts
puts "Errors:"
puts error_collector
```

My problem is the data collection and error handling.

1. I'm passing two arrays around, `collector` and `error_collector`, which doesn't seem right. I want to collect data and errors in one place, but the collector itself should simply implement a `<<` method (like an Array). Any advice how to improve it?
2. Generally, the error handling feels weird. I need it in two places: Logging parsing errors and validations on items. To identify the items I also need the name of a node, except when it's a parsing error. So there are two kinds of errors: Parsing and node validation errors. How could I improve this code and remove the code smells?
3. Any other advice how to improve the code above?